# selected for select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following code

```
select "sales", "price", @salesprice, {:selected => '#{@sales}'}
```

This is what is in @salesprice

```
[["All"], ["Sale"], ["Discount"], ["Free"]]
```

and when select something, and it renders the partial again, it returns whatever is this first element in the select tag :S

Any help is most appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be:

```
select "sales", "price", @salesprice, {:selected => "#{@sales}"}
```

with double quotes around the `#{@sales}`

Comment: thank you very much, stackoverflow is such a great place with wonderful helping people :) Have a great new years